# UICollectionView Header Compatible Views

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I've constructed an `UICollectionView` in a storyboard and implemented all of its required data source and delegate methods in the view controller. In the storyboard, I checked the `Section Header` property on the collection view and set the header view's class to a subclass of `UICollectionResusableView` (in the storyboard).

From here, I dragged in two UI elements onto the header view via the storyboard--a label and a segmented control:

[image]

When the program is executed, the label appears in the header view of the collection view (with no actual code required), but the segmented control does not. However, when a segmented control is dragged onto a typical `UIView`, it displays and is manipulatable with no code required. Even when instantiated through code in an `IBOutlet`, the segmented control does not appear.

Why is the segmented control not visible on the collection view's header while it is in a typical `UIView`, and why does the label display without issue?

**UPDATE**

Here is the init method for the custom header view, in which I attempted adding the segmented control programmatically (as opposed to in the storyboard):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil]];
        [_segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
        [_segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self addSubview:_segmentedControl];
    }
    return self;
}
```

As requested, here is the `-[UICollectionReusableView  viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:]` method in the main view controller:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    GalleryHeader *headerView = [cv dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the `uicollectionviewdatasource` method `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`?

Comment: Yes I did. I'll post the code for that too.

Comment: Ok, ill wait for the edit then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your storyboard problem, it works just fine for me when i add the segmented control by dragging it directly in the storyboard (with no code required). As for your alternative way of adding it programmatically, the problem here is that when a view is initialized from the storyboard (as it is in this case), the `initWithCoder` initializer method is used (not the `initWithFrame` initializer method). Hence, if you override that method, inserting the code in there, it should work:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        _segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil]];
        _segmentedControl.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
        [_segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self addSubview:_segmentedControl];
    }
    return self;
}
```

P.S. It doesnt affect this specific case, but you should just do:

```
GalleryHeader *headerView = [cv dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

instead of:

```
GalleryHeader *headerView = [cv dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

As it is the collection view that will ask for the right kind of view, you should worry about specifying it!

EDIT: The steps i followed to create the header from storyboard are:

- Select the collection view and tick the box labelled *Section Header*

[image]

- Select the newly created header and select the right class in the identity inspector

[image]

- Give the header section a unique identifier

[image]

- Drag the UI elements in the header in the storyboard (i also changed its background color)

[image]

- Finally implement the `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` method in your collection view's data source class

```
 -(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
          viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind 
                                atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     return [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"collectionViewHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 }
```

Let me know if you can spot any difference between what you did and what I did!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the `initWithFrame:` issue, and ovverode the `initWithCoder:` method instead, but to no avail. You mentioned that you weren't able to reproduce the storyboard problem. Perhaps you could send me the test project you made so I could compare the two side by side.

Comment: Im afraid it wouldn't be that simple to share the whole project, as i have some work stuff in it that i cannot share! Anyway hold on a second, how do you define _segmentedControl? Is it an outlet?

Comment: It's a simple property in the header file: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;`, so no, it's not an outlet.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share your project?

Comment: Sorry, confidential stuff on my end, too.

Comment: Ok, i'll edit my question and go step-by-step through what i did, maybe you can spot a difference from you did

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I really appreciate your time. I'm now getting an error: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader with identifier facade - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: Don't I need to actually instantiate `GalleryView` in the `-viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:` method?

Comment: no, just change the identifier (which i just put as facade) to the one you actually put in your storyboard! In my example I should have put it as collectionViewHeader (i now edited my answer again!). You dont need to actually instantiate it, as the dequeue method does that for you!

Comment: Once again, the label displays, but the segmented control does not.

Comment: If I could reproduce the problem I might be able to help, but it just shows for me! Try to put the following code in your initWithFramer method and let me know what the output is: `self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
 for( UIView *view in self.subviews )
  NSLog(@"%@", [view class]);
 return self;`

Comment: Sure enough, it does indicate `UISegmentedControl` as a subview. Perhaps there is just a display issue, then?

Comment: My guess is that you're using autolayout and some dodgy constraint is being the cause of all this!

Comment: just try disabling autolayout to confirm it

Comment: Autolayout disabled, no effect. But the control is definitely being added as a subview.

Comment: Gosh, this is getting quite frustrating. I wish i could just put my hands on that project!

Comment: I think I may have spotted the problem. There is a "View as" pulldown menu that allows me to view the project from an iOS 7 or iOS 6 point of view. When I clicked on iOS 7, the segmented control went away. That looks to be the problem. Give me just a moment to confirm.

Comment: Yup, that was clearly the source of the problem - looks like an iOS 7 gimik. Thanks very much for all your help and for leading me to the right answer. 50 points to you.

Comment: Thanks to you, it was quite a boring afternoon before :)